# multiplication table with header

Tags: javascript

I'm making a multiplication table, and I cannot figure out how to make the header of the table like this:

[image]

This is my code, and I'm almost there. Instead of the number in the corner, I want an X. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
 function multiplication_table(a, b) {
    var table = "<table style='width:500px'>";
    var product, n_1, n_2;

    for (n_2 = a - 1; n_2 <= b; n_2++) {
     table += "<th>" + n_2 + "</th>";
    }

    for (n_1 = a; n_1 <= b; n_1++) {
      table += "<tr>";

      table += "<th>" + n_1 + "</th>";
      for (n_2 = a; n_2 <= b; n_2++) {
        product = n_1 * n_2;
        table += "<td>" + product + "</td>";
      }
      table += "</tr>";
    }
    table += "</table>";

    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = table;
  }
```

Comment: Your first loop should be just `n_2 = a` (remove the `-1`), and before that loop put in the `x` cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can solve your problem

```
function multiplication_table(a, b) {
var table = "<table style='width:500px'>";
var product, n_1, n_2;

for (n_2 = a - 1; n_2 <= b; n_2++) {
    if(n_2==a-1)
        table += "<th>x</th>";
    else
        table += "<th>" + n_2 + "</th>";
}

for (n_1 = a; n_1 <= b; n_1++) {
  table += "<tr>";

  table += "<th>" + n_1 + "</th>";
  for (n_2 = a; n_2 <= b; n_2++) {
    product = n_1 * n_2;
    table += "<td>" + product + "</td>";
  }
  table += "</tr>";
}
table += "</table>";

document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = table;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just before your first for loop, add:

```
table += "<th>x</th>";
```

Then, if you're producing one too many TH elements because of the addition, change:

```
for (n_2 = a - 1; n_2 <= b; n_2++) {
```

to:

```
for (n_2 = a; n_2 <= b; n_2++) {
```